# Spy story with a sci-fi element

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, espionage

The story was about an American spy on the track of (probably) some Russian spies. For some reason he had a device that enabled him to go backward (forward?) in time by a few minutes. I'm pretty sure that the film was made in America and I think I saw it in either the mid 1960's or (at the latest) the early 1970's. I checked out the following [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_films_of_the_1960s) page and at first thought it might have been  "Agent for H.A.R.M." (using the logic sci-fi film involving spies) but this proved fruitless.

Comment: I saw a film called Agent for H.A.R.M once- well ,actually it was shown and mocked on MST3K- there was nothing in the film itself about time travel, though.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Look like it, and Jeffrey Hunter certainly rings true as one of the spies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Could this be *[Dimension 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_5_(film))*?

The spy protagonist has a time travel device:

> What happened? What was that device? Did he teleport? No, in fact he
>   time-traveled. Which is later explained as travel to another
>   dimension, "the fifth dimension." Not explained: why they skipped the
>   fourth dimension, or how dimensional travel equals time travel.

It was made in 1966, so it fits your timeframe.

The enemy spies were from Southeast Asia, I think, not Russia.